# Rectangle is not showing up (paint) java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've done this plenty of times but I'm stuck. I've checked previous projects of mine and can't find the answer. The rectangle is supposed to show up at 400,400 and be 100,100 big, (Bottom right corner). When the start button is press I want it to show the rectangle. Thanks in advance!

!!!: There are multiple classes in this I just didn't post them since they don't have a use, if they do I'll post them.

```java
class MazeRunner extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseMotionListener {
    JButton b1;
    int  pkp = 0;

    MazeRunner(){
        b1= new JButton("Start");
        add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b1.setBounds(10,10,50,50);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setTitle("Maze Runner");
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MazeRunner();  
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == b1){ 
            remove(b1);
            pkp++;
            validate();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        if (pkp == 1) {
            if(e.getX() >= 400 && e.getX() <= 500 && e.getY() >= 400 && e.getY() <= 500) {
                dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        draw(g);
    }

    private void draw(Graphics g) {
        if(pkp == 1) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(400, 400, 100, 100);
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't override the draw/paint/update methods of your JFrame, draw on a subclassed component that you add to the content pane.    You should work through the Swing tutorial to learn the basics of how this stuff works.  Especially see https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html for an overview of the paint chain and indications of how it may have changed since you last used it.

Comment: When you extend a JComponent and override paintComponent, you must always call super.paintComponent, although I agree that it's better to subclass, say, a JPanel and add it to the content pane rather than extending JFrame. Your immediate problem is that a JFrame is not a JComponent, and as such, it doesn't even *have* a paintComponent method. If you annotated it with `@Override` the compiler would have told you you weren't overriding anything. When you do override it (on some JComponent), the access modifier needs to be `public`.

Comment: **Add `@Override` notation** to ***every*** method overridden.

Answer (score -2):

First of all the method `paintComponent()` is missing it's constructor so it should look like

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    draw(g);
}
```

second of all, im not sure if `Graphics g` object has a method called "fillRect"
so I would recommend you to convert it to object of type `Graphics2D`, so in this case it would be:

```
public void draw(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    if(pkp == 1) {
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillRect(400, 400, 100, 100);
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: 1) *"im not sure if `Graphics g` object has a method called "fillRect""* That's why we have [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect(int,int,int,int)). Please check them before answering. 2) No methods have constructors.

Comment: You're not sure if `Graphics` has a method called `fillRect`? Did it occur to you to look before posting an answer? The method cannot be `missing its [note spelling] constructor` since methods don't have constructors, however `JFrame` doesn't have a `paintComponent` method at all since it is not a `JComponent`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).